# Mostrar consulta ajax en gridview o tabla VB.NET

Tags: json, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

Estoy haciendo una aplicación *AJAX* en *VB.NET* que muestre los registros de una consulta en un gridview, hasta el momento solo puedo mostrar los datos en una cadena JSON pero no se como mostrarlos en un gridview o una tabla.

Actualmente solo me muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código JavaScript es:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnmostrar').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/Mostrar",
                data: null,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function (resultado) {

                 $('#msg').html(JSON.stringify(resultado));

                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest + "  " + textStatus + "  " + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    });        
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Y en que tipo de tabla quieres mostrar la info? Algún widget, o plugin o quieres generar la tabla manualmente?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Si quieres usar gridview modifica la línea de JS

```
$('#msg').html(JSON.stringify(resultado));
```

Para hacer algo como esto:

```
var row = $("[id*=msg] tr:last-child").clone(true); 
var resultados=JSON.stringify(resultado);
$("[id*=msg] tr").not($("[id*=msg] tr:first-child")).remove();
    $.each(resultados, function () {
        var res= $(this);
        $("td", row).eq(0).html(res.Id);
        $("td", row).eq(1).html(res.Nombre);
        $("td", row).eq(2).html(res.Edad));
        $("[id*=msg]").append(row); //AQUI ESTA AGREGANDO LOS RENGLONES
        row = $("[id*=msg] tr:last-child").clone(true);
    });
```

[Aquí](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-data-to-GridView-with-jQuery-or-JSON-in-ASPNet.aspx) esta un ejemplo completo, pero básicamente la idea es llenar el gridview como una tabla html, no hace un binding automático, eso lo utiliza en el codebehind.

Solo ten cuidado por que en el ejemplo que te comento usa XML, no JSON, no podrías usar el código exactamente como se ve, tienes que adecuarlo un poco

Comment: Sabes cual es el problema con alterar el html del gridview, si algun control realida un submit a su evento asp.net detectara esta modificacion y genera un exception. Tiene que ver con la deteccion de un ataque por script injection https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647397.aspx  Es por eso que no recomiendo alterar el html del gridview desde codigo cliente

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @LeandroTuttini, creo que no es buena idea usar un GridView de esta manera. La forma de hacerlo sería con un UdatePanel https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb386452(v=vs.100).aspx o usando un control Grid de jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Combinar codigo javascript y json con controles de asp.net no es buena idea, mas que nada porque asp.net no se lleva bien con codigo del lado del cliente.

Mi recomendacion es que descartes el uso del gridview si piensas usar ajax

El mejor camino seria usar librerias como ser jqGrid, no se si te animas, sino hay otras alternativas como puede ser generar algun template que defina una la tabla en base a unir json con html

[jQuery (jTemplates) Grid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45759/jQuery-jTemplates-Grid)

como veras puedes combinar ajax y un template para generar la tabla

Remarco, si tu intencion es ir por el camino de usar codigo cliente con javascript, jquery y json ve pensando en dejar de lado asp.net y sus controles del lado del servidor, lo digo por experiencia.
Como habia recomendado deberias volcarte por asp.net mvc este tiene un mejor soporte para programar con codigo cliente.